# Why can I not define a member function in a class if that function is to be linked from another translation unit?

Tags: c++, header

I am a bit of a newbie in C++, but I just stumbled on the following.

If I have these files:

myclass.hpp:

```
class myclass {
public:
  myclass();
  void barf();
};
```

mymain.cpp:

```
#include "myclass.hpp"

int main() {
  myclass m;
  m.barf();
  return 0;
}
```

And I use this implementation of myclass:

myclassA.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class myclass {   // or include myclass.hpp, it both works fine
public:
  myclass();
  void barf();
};

myclass::myclass() { } //empty
void myclass::barf() {
  cout << "barfing\n";
}
```

then everything is OK. But if I use this implementation of myclass, which is exactly the same except the members are defined inside the class definition, I get a linking error:

myclassB.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class myclass {
public:
  myclass() { }
  void barf() {
    cout << "barfing\n";
  }
};
```

The error I get:

```
$ g++ myclassB.cpp mymain.cpp
/tmp/cc4DTnDl.o: In function `main':
mymain.cpp:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `myclass::myclass()'
mymain.cpp:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `myclass::barf()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Apparently the object file built from myclassB.cpp doesn't export the member functions. Why aren't both of these implementations behaving te same? Is there some gotcha rule in C++ that says member definitions inside class definitions are not globally visible, but they are if they are defined outside of the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

standard that says that there must be a unique definition of a class,
template, etc., is phrased in a somewhat more complicated and subtle manner. This rule is commonly referred to as ‘‘the one definition rule,’’ the ODR. That is, two definitions of a class, template,
or inline function are accepted as examples of the same unique definition if and only if
[1] they appear in different translation units, and
[2] they are tokenfortoken
identical, and
[3] the meanings of those tokens are the same in both translation units.

For example (valid):

```
// file1.c:
struct S { int a ; char b ; };
void f(S* p){ }   
// file2.c:
struct S { int a ; char b ; };
void f(S* p){ }
```

Examples that violate ODR:

```
file1.c:
struct S 1 { int a ; char b ; };
struct S 1 { int a ; char b ; }; // error: double definition
This is an error because a struct may not be defined twice in a single 
translation unit.

// file1.c:
struct S 2 { int a ; char b ; };
// file2.c:

struct S 2 { int a ; char b b ; }; // error.
This is an error because S2 is used to name classes that differ in a member name.

// file1.c:
typedef int X ;
struct S 3 { X a ; char b ; };
// file2.c:
typedef char X ;
struct S 3 { X a ; char b ; }; // error.
Here the two definitions of S3 are    
token for token identical, but the example is an error because the
meaning of the name X has sneakily been made to differ in the two files.
```

Comment: To me his question sounded like he actually defined the class only once, but that definition was inside a second class declaration inside his source file.

Comment: He had myclass.hpp included in mymain.cpp and then trying to compile with g++ myclassB.cpp mymain.cpp.

Answer (score 1):

Member functions defined inline are candidates to be inlined by the compiler.  If it's never used, and only defined inline inside of a source file, I suspect your compiler is removing the method altogether.

That being said, I highly recommend putting your declaration in a header file, and just have the definitions in your .cpp files.  Include the header file (with the appropriate guards, such as `#pragma once` or `#idfef/#define` guards.  You will need to do this as your projects get larger, so it's best to just build the appropriate practices now.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jagannaths answer, I thought the definition of myclass in myclass.hpp counted as a declaration, but in C++ it is a definition so Jagannaths answer applies. It turns out it is possible to just declare a class but then you can only use pointers or references to that class, but not access its members in any way. see also: [Declare a C++ class without defining it in the current translation unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194734/declare-a-c-class-without-defining-it-in-the-current-translation-unit)